# React-Native: How to verify which page / route is used to handle an if condition

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation

I'm pretty new in the reactive native world ...
I wanted to know how to pass properties in order to verify from which path / page arrives.
I need it because I would like to put a check (if) on a screen to keep the logo in the top half of the page and only edit the form.

> Login.js (base page)

```
export default class Login extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
}
render() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.props));
    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
                    <Image
                        style={styles.logo}
                        source={require('../../images/XXX.png')}/>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.formContainer}>
                    <LoginForm navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
                </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
    }
}
```

> loginForm.js

```
export default class LoginForm extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
}
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput
                placeholder="Username or email"
                placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
                underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                returnKeyType="next"
                onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordInput.focus()}
                keyboardType="email-address"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                autoCorrect={false}
                style={styles.input}
            />
            <TextInput
                placeholder="Password"
                placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
                underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                secureTextEntry
                returnKeyType="go"
                autoCapitalize="none"
                style={styles.input}
                ref={(input) => this.passwordInput = input}
            />

            <Icon.Button style={styles.buttonContainer} name="user-circle" justifyContent="center">LOGIN
            </Icon.Button>

            <TouchableOpacity
                activeOpacity={.5}
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('ForgetPassword')}
            >
                <Text style={[styles.forgetPassword]}>Forget Password?</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

> forgetPassword.js

```
export default class ForgetPassword extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
}

render() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.props));
    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
                <Image
                    style={styles.logo}
                    source={require('../../images/XXX.png')}/>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.formContainer}>

                <View style={styles.containerText}>
                    <TextInput
                        placeholder="Username or email"
                        placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
                        underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                        returnKeyType="next"
                        onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordInput.focus()}
                        keyboardType="email-address"
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                        autoCorrect={false}
                        style={styles.input}
                    />

                    <Icon.Button style={styles.buttonContainer} name="unlock" justifyContent="center">RECOVER PASSWORD
                    </Icon.Button>
                </View>
            </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}
```

now, what I want is to be able to manage everything from the login.js page passing just either loginForm.js or forgetPasswordForm.js (yet to be created but at that point will contain only the TextInput) depending on whether the user clicks on "Forget Password ? " (in loginForm.js).
practically like this:

```
export default class Login extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
}
render() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.props));
    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
                    <Image
                        style={styles.logo}
                        source={require('../../images/XXX.png')}/>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.formContainer}>
                    if (ROUTE != FORGETPASSWORD)
                <LoginForm navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
                    else
                <ForgetPasswordForm navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
                </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you use Redux** they provide a function to get the current routeName in the [`react-navigation` docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/screen-tracking.html#listening-to-state-changes)

```js
function getActiveRouteName(navigationState) {
  if (!navigationState) {
    return null;
  }
  const route = navigationState.routes[navigationState.index];
  // dive into nested navigators
  if (route.routes) {
    return getActiveRouteName(route);
  }
  return route.routeName;
}
```

So you can easily get the current route name by using `getActiveRouteName(yourNavigationState)` and then display your component only on a specific route

```js
<View>
  …
  {
    getActiveRouteName(yourNavigationState) !== 'ForgetPassword' ? 
      <LoginForm /> : <ForgetPasswordForm />
  }
  …
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass props down the component tree, by writing them next to the component. [Here are the official React Docs.](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#composing-components) If you read their example they are passing the prop "name" to the `<Welcome>` component. In the `<Welcome>` component you would now have access to `this.props.name`.